# [JSON][JODA] Formatting DateTIme

Tags: json, spring, jpa

I'm using Spring boot + JPA to create Restful webservice.
It works fine, but the time format in returned JSON is not correctly formatted

> "created": 1440327152688,
>     "updated": 1440327152689,
>     "birth": [
>       2017,
>       1,
>       1
>     ]

I would like something like :

> "created": 2013-08-23 18:19:12:01,
>     "updated": 2013-08-23 18:19:12:01,
>     "birth": 2013-08-23

In other topics, I see it is possible to use jackson databind but I dont really know how use the mapper:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.registerModule(new JodaModule());
```

In Bean :

```
@Column(nullable = false)
@Type(type = "org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentDateTime")
private DateTime created;

@Column(nullable = false)
@Type(type = "org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentDateTime")
private DateTime updated;
```

In my BeanService :

```
public Entry create(Entry entity) {
   entity.setCreated(new DateTime());
   entity.setUpdated(new DateTime());
   return entryDao.save(entity);
}
```

My Controller :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/createEntry", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public Entry create(@RequestBody Entry activityType){
    return this.entryService.create(activityType);
}
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

I've just found.
I need just add this line in application.properties :

```
spring.jackson.serialization.write_dates_as_timestamps=false
```

And if I want to change format, to add this annotation :

```
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss")
```